# MySQL - High CPU long after executing update

Tags: mysql, rds

I have a MySQL database running in Amazon RDS that serves a  site. Around 80MB of data in one of the tables gets replaced hourly. I load the data into another table and then use rename to swap the tables and then delete the other table.

Most of the time everything is fine. When the update happens hourly, there is a CPU spike to around to 10% and back to 2% or 3%, which is the CPU consumption with normal site traffic.

Once in a while (no pattern), however, the CPU spikes to almost 100% right at the time of the update and stays very high until the next update an hour later, long after the update is completed. The update takes seconds. During the entire hour, traffic to the site is normal. Also, during that time, `show processlist` is empty - no stuck processes.

A couple of times, I manually triggered the update before the hour ended and the CPU went back to normal.

My question is this: Assuming there is something inefficient going on with the data loading, **can a bad query or update cause the CPU to stay high long after it completes executing**?

I will run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` next time it happens. When I do, what should I be looking for?

Some details if useful:

- RDS m4.large instance running in multi-az
- MySQL version 5.6.27
- InnoDB engine
- Connection pool used with default 8 connections

Comment: Are you sure it is MySQL that causes the spike in CPU utilisation? I understand that an operation in MySQL may trigger it, but it can even be some kind of a backup or synchronisation process that gets fooled by the operation and hence the spike.

Comment: I'm sure it is being triggered by MySQL because the spike starts with the update and ends with the next update an hour later. How can a MySQL operation trigger a non-MySQL process? Also note that this runs in RDS, there are no other applications running inside the OS instance.

Comment: It is the CPU of the MySQL process itself that is spiking.

Comment: I was not talking about another application. I was talking about some kind of background process that is related to the RDS instance. To be honest, I do not think this question is at the right Q/A site. This does not seem to be a programming issue, more like an admin issue on DBA or sysadmin level.